# MongoDB replica with some writes to only one server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-replication, replicaset

I'm working on a node.js application which has 2 servers.
One of them is considered `production` server and the second one is considered `dataAnalytics` server.

Currently all data is being written into `production` collections except one collection, with very high volume data, that is only written in `dataAnalytics`. I've also deployed a script that syncs `production` to `dataAnalytics` every 4 hours:

- collectionP1: `production` (and `dataAnalytics` update every 4h)
- collectionP2: `production` (and `dataAnalytics` update every 4h)
- ...
- collectionDA1: `dataAnalytics` (high volume, not in `production`)

In mongoose I've achieved with:

```js
await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');
const daCn = await createConnection('mongodb://da.vrack:27017');

const collectionP1 = mongoose.model(new Schema(...));
const collectionP2 = mongoose.model(new Schema(...));
...
const collectionDA1 = daCn.model(new Schema(...));
```

This is working fine, and currently the data is being saved separately.

I would like to take advantage of mongodb replication. I understood that to create a replica set it is required a third server, and it would be even desirable to have a backup server only with `production` data (without *collectionDA1*).

**Q.** Is it possible to create a replica set with those two servers (or three considering `backup`) and keep only some writes in `dataAnalytics`? What I'm not sure is what would happen if `production` fails, `dataAnalytics` starts being primary and then `production` recovers but `dataAnalytics` keeps being primary... I wouldn't like that all the records from *collectionDA1* suddenly starts appearing in `production` server.

In case of not possible, is there any better approach than what I've described?

Comment: Just a general note: "replica set" means **all** data is written to **all** replica set members. There is no possibility to define "data xyz is not/only written to certain member".

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit does it mean that I could not use mongoose to connect to `dataAnalytics` server (part of replica set with priority 0 and votes 0) and write some data directly and only to this server?

Comment: Correct, you cannot. You can write only to the PRIMARY - nothing else, period! You can connect to SECONDARY for reading only.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: You can create replicaSet also with only two servers , but the second server need to set as HIDDEN and not electable for PRIMARY, but this way you dont have auto failover option. In case or problem with the PRIMARY you will need to manually re-configure the HIDDEN to PRIMARY.

Option 2: From the details you have added it looks best to create replicaSet with PRIMARY+SECONDARY+ARBITER where you are going to use your SECONDARY member as
dataAnalytics ( your analytics application will read with secondaryPreffered read option and from time to time you will make backup from the SECONDARY )

Option 3: You create replicaSet with 3x members 1st PRIMARY ( reads + writes)  , 2nd SECONDARY( analytics - only reads ) , 3th SECONDARY ( backups ) .

Comment: Thanks @R2D2! In those options, could I keep writing with mongoose as I've described? So what I'm not sure is if I could attach writes to only one node or how I would manage to attach writes to one node in concrete... I mean, can I make a connection to one node?

Comment: You can make a connection to single node , but if you configure replicaSet it is best to connect to the replicaSet , this way the driver will identify autmatically which node is the PRIMARY so it forward the writes to that node

Comment: So if I understood well, mongoose will connect to the replicaSet, in this case 127.0.0.1 and also to da.vrack as described in question. On the other hand, in Option 3 I should config 127.0.0.1 mongod as replicaSet and add the da.vrack with only reads and a 3rd secondary that could become primary when 1st fails, is correct?

Comment: You can deploy all the mongoDB members even in single server like 127.0.0.1:X , 127.0.0.1:Y, 127.0.0.1:Z  where X,Y,Z some chosen TCP ports , but for high redundancy better use more servers ...

Comment: when you have at least 3 members in replcaSet they can allow PRIMARY to be elected even you have one of the 3 members down